# Is the C standard time() function thread safe even if provided a NULL parameter?

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

Seems like bit of a silly question but it got me thinking...

According to [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/xsh_chap02_09.html#tag_02_09_01), `time` is required to be thread safe on a compliant system, correct? This requirement holds regardless of the parameters to the function. A few functions are listed as not required to be thread safe if provided a `NULL` argument, and `time` is not included.

So it looks like any sufficiently `POSIX` compliant system should have a thread safe implementation of `time`.

However, could a POSIX system choose to implement `time_t` in a matter which actually makes it a pointer and still be compliant? So if a NULL parameter is provided to store the result, then wouldn't all bets on its thread safety be off as it would likely return a pointer to some static storage? Or is there some requirement or convention for `time_t` that I'm missing in this aspect?

How would I best go about verifying that `time` is thread safe on a few `UNIX` platforms? Particularly, `AIX`, `HP-UX`, `Linux`, and `Solaris`. Stepping through the disassembly in a debugger could work, but the implementations may change.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/types.h.html : time_t and clock_t shall be integer or real-floating types. Assigning them should be thread-safe.

Comment: `time` is a silly enough function as is. We can't break its signature for compatibility reasons, but there was little reason to make it even sillier and allow thread-unsafe implementations.

Comment: @marcolz Thank you. Not sure how I missed that.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is thread safe.

```
time_t time( NULL );
```

If it implemented an internal value, at the point it returned, it would always have to copy from the internal value to the return value (register?).  That copy would make it thread-safe as it would fit in all modern processors single copy.

```
mov eax, static_internal_value
return
```

Imagine that wasn't the case, and 2 threads came in.  They would both copy out the same value - again, can't see how this could be incorrect.

```
thread 1                                    thread 2
                                            mov eax, static_internal_value
mov eax, static_internal_value
return 
                                            return
```

Comment: A few things. I wasn't aware of the requirement for `time_t` to be an integer or floating point type. That throws out my hypothetical pointer situation. Second, your post is assuming an atomic double word store. Which is usually true, but x86 architecture is not the arch of the platforms I listed. Even with the requirement for `time_t` to be an integer or floating point, a compliant implementation could have an 8 byte `time_t` which may not have atomic load/store on some platforms. The POSIX spec says `time` is required to be thread safe, and so it is.